Conjugation with 는데
In the song "너였다면", there is a line that says "다 알면서도 난 모르는 척 맴도는데".
I understand the sentence but am wondering if 맴도 here means "to linger" or "to hover around"? If so, why is it not conjugated as 맴돌는데 (from 맴돌다)?
My guess is that, while adjectives can be used with +은데/는데, verbs can only be used with 는데. Since 맴돌 ends in a consonant, we can't simply add 는데 so we drop the 'ㄹ'?
But then I thought we could still leave it as 맴돌는데 but pronounce it as [맴돌:른데]? (similar to how 설날 is pronounced as [설:랄])
Couldn't seem to find a grammatical rule for this so I just wanted to make sure. 감사합니당^^

https://kcenter.korean.go.kr/kcenter/search/dgrammar/view.do?mode=view&id=751&searchTabMenu=

① 동사 어간 끝음절의 받침 유무에 관계없이 ‘-는데’를 쓴다. 단, ‘ㄹ’ 받침으로 끝날 때는 ‘ㄹ’이 탈락한다. ex)사는데, 미는데, 만드는데

링크 주셔서 너무 감사합니다. 한국어를 더 열심히 공부해야겠네~
